# puppeteer: Different response from the puppeteer browser and the user browser

Tags: puppeteer

I use my own browser to get the result page I want. Everything is correct. Page link is below.
https://parcelsapp.com/en/tracking/016-35294405
[img for working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C62pj.jpg)
I want to use puppeteer to help me to load the result page. The page shows differently.
I use options headless=false to debug. I found the browser pop up from puppeteer can not load the url correctly. I guess it is because the different environments. How can I solve the problem? Thank you.
[img for not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfHtq.png)

My code is below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 250, // slow down by 250ms
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.on("request", (request) => {
        request.abort();
    });
    await page.goto('https://parcelsapp.com/en/tracking/016-35294405');
    await page.waitForNavigation()
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'result.png' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Can you try `puppeteer.launch({ defaultViewport: null })`?

Comment: this doesn't work neither.